# Bowling calculator

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a bowling score calculator in Ruby that is defined and tested using RSpec. It currently runs, but only passes 5 of the 8 input tests. Here is the code for my implementation:

```
    class ScoreKeeper
  def calculate(input)
    unless input.is_a? String
      raise argumentException, "Score Keeper will only except string types for score calculation."
    end

    # Thanksgiving Turkey Edge Case
    return 300 if input == "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

    # Calculate Score   
    throws = input.gsub(/-/, "0").split(//)

    score = 0

    throws.each_with_index do |ball, i|
        current_throw = i
        last_throw = throws[i - 1] || "0"
        lastlast_throw = throws[i - 2] || "0"
        next_throw = throws[i + 1] || "0"

        if current_throw == 0
            last_throw = 0
            lastlast_throw = 0
        end

        if current_throw == 1
            lastlast_throw = 0
        end

        working_value = 0

        # Add numbers directly (unless part of a spare frame)
        if ((1..9) === ball.to_i)
            working_value = ball.to_i
        end

        # Add strike as 10 points
        if ball == "x"
            working_value = 10
        end

        # Add spare as number of remaining pins from last throw
        if ball == "/"
            if last_throw == "/" || last_throw == "x"
                raise argumentException, "Invalid score string. A spare cannot immediately follow a strike or spare."
            end

            working_value = 10 - last_throw.to_i
        end

        # Strike / Spare Bonus
        if last_throw == "x" || last_throw == "/" || lastlast_throw == "x"
            score += working_value
        end

        # Add current throw value
        score += working_value      
    end

    if score > 300 || score < 0
        raise argumentExcpetion, "Invalid score string. Impossible score detected."
    end

    score   
  end
end
```

I can't tell why my code is not calculating a proper score in every test case.

The RSpec:

```
require "./score_keeper"

describe ScoreKeeper do
  describe "calculating score" do
    let(:score_keeper) { described_class.new }

    context "when rolls are valid" do
      {
        "xxxxxxxxxxxx"          => 300,
        "--------------------"  => 0,
        "9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-9-"  => 90,
        "5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5" => 150,
        "14456/5/---17/6/--2/6" => 82,
        "9/3561368153258-7181"  => 86,
        "9-3/613/815/0/8-7/8-"  => 121,
        "x3/61xxx2/9-7/xxx"     => 193
      }.each do |bowling_stats, score|

        it "returns #{score} for #{bowling_stats}" do
          expect(score_keeper.calculate(bowling_stats)).to eq score
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```

The failing inputs are:

- "5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5/5" (expected: 150, got: 155),
- "x3/61xxx2/9-7/xxx" (expected: 82, got: 88),
- "14456/5/---17/6/--2/6" (expected: 193, got: 223)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's necessary to provide sample input and your expected output when asking for help debugging code. Without that we have to cobble something up, which is error prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I see is your use of [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
input.gsub(/-/, "0")
```

You're not assigning the string returned by [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub) to anything, and instead you're throwing it away.

```
input = '#0#'
input.gsub('0', '-') # => "#-#"
input # => "#0#"
```

I suspect you're thinking of the mutating [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) but instead I suggest simply passing the value to [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#method-c-split):

```
_frames = input.gsub(/-/, "0").split(//)
```

Your code is not idiomatic Ruby; There are a number of things you need to do differently:

- Instead of `if !input.is_a? String` use:

  ```
  unless input.is_a? String
    raise argumentException, "Score Keeper will only except string types for score calculation."
  end
  ```

  It's considered better to use `unless` than a negated test.
- Instead of

  ```
  if input == "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      return 300
  end
  ```

  use a "trailing if":

  ```
  return 300 if input == "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ```
- Don't name variables with a leading `_`. `_frames` should be `frames`.
- Don't name variables like `lastFrame`, `lastlastFrame` and `workingValue` with mixed-case AKA "camelCase". We use "snake_case" for Ruby variables and methods and camelCase for classes and modules. It_is_a matterOfReadability.
- Don't end lines with a trailing `;`:

  ```
  workingValue = 0;
  ```

  The only time we use a trailing semicolon is when we're using multiple statements on a single line, which should be extremely rare. Just don't do that unless you know why and when you should.
- Consider the potential problem you have here:

  ```
  "12".include?('1') # => true
  "12".include?('2') # => true
  "12".include?('12') # => true
  ```

  While your code might skirt that issue, don't write code like that and think about side-effects. Perhaps you want to really test to see if the value is an integer between 1 and 9?

  ```
  ((1 .. 9) === '1'.to_i) # => true
  ((1 .. 9) === '2'.to_i) # => true
  ((1 .. 9) === '12'.to_i) # => false
  ```
- Instead of using

  ```
  return score
  ```

  you can simply use

  ```
  score
  ```

  Ruby will return the last value seen; You don't have to explicitly return it.
- Indent your code properly. Your future self will appreciate it when you have to dive back into code to debug something. Consistenly use two space indents.
- Use whitespace liberally to separate your code into readable blocks. It doesn't affect the run-time speed of your code and it makes it a lot easier to read. Again, your future self will appreciate it.

While it might seem nit-picking, those little things go a long way when coding in a team of developers, and failing to do those things can land you in the hot seat during a code-review.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem appears to be that that for your first two frames you're adding the last two frames.  Consider the following.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
arr.each_with_index do |num, i|
  puts "current number #{num}"
  puts arr[i-1]
  puts arr[i-2]
end
```

I think you need an if statement to handle the first two frames because - index will loop back to the end of the array if you're at 0 index.

so you need something like

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

arr.each_with_index do |num, i|
  puts "current number #{num}"
  if i <= 1
    puts "no previous frame"
  elsif i == 1
    puts arr[i-1] + "can be added to frame 2"
  else
    puts arr[i-1] + "can be added to frame 1"
    puts arr[i-2] + "can be added to frame 2"
  end

end
```